# Bulk URL Redirection in Ingress kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, http-redirect

I have sheet including many URLS I want to redirecting one by one on other URL using ingress rules in Kubernetes. Please Help
I tried nginx annotations but i didn't find the way which i want. I'm assuming, is there any way to using the map in ingress?.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: hii bot, For ex. I have a URL like "stati.example.com/something/rain" ok, I want to redirect this on to "example.com/something/rain-coming" right, likewise other 50 to 70 URLS that I need to redirect using Ingress Kubernetes.